# MVC2 Devexpress Gridview. How to call a Clientside Javascript function after the databound?

Tags: javascript, gridview, asp.net-mvc-2, devexpress-mvc

How can I call a Javascript function after data binding is completed ?

I have already tried EndCallback but it doesnot work when the Grid is loaded for the first time because I use RenderAction to display the partialview which contains gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using RenderAction I used RenderPartial and used Grid.Refresh() on Clientside Init event of the grid, to make sure that endcallback gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use OnInit from GridView client side event, standard javascript window.onload, or jQuery $(document).ready event handlers.